# Spring Authorization Server Legacy Stack

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Good Day All,

Is it possible to have different token validity seconds depending on the grant type ?
I want to to have the access tokens that are issued with "client_credentials" grant type last longer than access tokens issued with "password" grant type.

This is how its currently configured.

```
 @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws  Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret( passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .scopes("read")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password","refresh_token");
    }
```

Client credentials token is used to make sure that any requests are coming from the correct client application. These end-ponits do not require a user to be logged in.

Password credentials token is issued when a user logs in. They are only valid for 5 minutes and get refreshed using refresh token.

This all works fine until I realized that client credentials token also expires after 5 minutes.

Which leads to my original question ?

Can I specify different "Access Token Validity Seconds" depending the grant type ?

Thanks All your help is always highly appreciated

Comment: The easiest way is to use two different clients wiith different configurations. This makes sense, because the client credentials grant is use for non-human access, which should separated from hunman access client.

Comment: @dur Thanks for your answer. It makes sense but then how do I configure it because we use the UserDetailsService interface implementation to load users from the db. Sorry for the time delay i'm sitting in Africa

Comment: AFAIR the client credential grant type doesn't use the authorization endpoint, because that would trigger the form login. It uses the basic auth and in this case the `UserDetailsService`  is not used. Your client shouldn't have an own user in the user database.